# Grails Controller Action Abstract Command Object Parameter

Tags: grails, grails-controller, command-objects

Is there any support for using abstract command objects in controller action parameters? Then depending on the given parameters in a JSON request it would select the correct command object?

For example something like:

```
class SomeController {

    def someAction(BaseCommand cmd){
        // cmd could be instance of ChildCommandOne or ChildCommandTwo
    }

    class BaseCommand {
        String paramOne
    }

    class ChildCommandOne extends BaseCommand {
        String paramTwo
    }

    class ChildCommandTwo extends BaseCommand {
        String paramThree
    }

}
```

As of now I've been using `request.JSON` to detect the passed in parameters and instantiate the correct Command object. Is that my only option to handle this sort of case?

**EDIT :**

To clarify the use case here. I have two domain models that share the same base class domain model and I'm modeling the inheritance in the database using the default `table-per-hierarchy` model.

In my case, one of the child domain models `Model A` requires a non-nullable String called `body`, that is a Text entry, while the other  `Model B` requires a non-nullable String called `directUrl`. These represent announcements that can be made on the platform. `Model A` being a write in entry that contains the announcement body while `Model B` represents a link to a third party site that contains the actual announcement.

In these sort of scenarios I've traditionally put an if statement in the controller action that determines which related command object to instantiate but I am hoping for a cleaner method.

Comment: Well I dont think its a good approach, if you have 3 different commands, why dont u create 3 different actions ? Maybe it would be easier if u explained your use case

Comment: @rgrebski I've updated the question to contain my actual use case. Additionally how might I distinguish between the 3 actions without having to formally declare separate endpoints in my url mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work this way. Grails needs a concrete class (with default public constructor) to `bind` request params to a command object instance. Therefore this class is to be defined explicitely as action's argument.

Comment: So traditionally how would somebody handle this case? Use separate endpoints to distinguish between the different commands?

Comment: call the `bindData()` on a specific instance yourself. it's simple

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to call binding manually depending on what map contains.
See RootModel.from(Map map). In your case Map would be params from Controller

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class CommandHierarchySpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    def "should create object of type #type for map: #map"() {
        when:
            def modelObj = RootModel.from(map)
        then:
            modelObj.class == type
        where:
            type   | map
            ModelA | [body: 'someBody', test: 'test']
            ModelB | [directUrl: 'directUrl', test: 'test']
    }

    def "should throw ISE when map does not contain neither body nor url"() {
        when:
            RootModel.from(a: 'b')
        then:
            thrown(IllegalStateException)
    }
}


abstract class RootModel {
    static RootModel from(Map map) {
        checkNotNull(map, "Parameter map mustn't be null")

        RootModel rootModel
        if (map.body) {
            rootModel = new ModelA()
        } else if (map.directUrl) {
            rootModel = new ModelB()
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot determine command type for map: $map")
        }

        map.findAll { key, value -> rootModel.hasProperty(key) }
                .each {
            rootModel.setProperty(it.key, it.value)
        }

        rootModel
    }
}

class ModelA extends RootModel {
    String body
}

class ModelB extends RootModel {
    String directUrl
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. To play off of it, I think I could annotate the domain command objects that are valid and have a discriminator annotation that annotates the property that distinguishes it between the other commands. Then test till I find the first command object that has a matching discriminator property in the parameter map.